# How to stop Thread in other function

Tags: multithreading, function

I have a game with thread. I new this thread in function StartGame() and I want stop this thread at function GameOver(). How can do it?

Comment: Can you give more information, like what language and what system you are using. The question is not clear enough without such detail.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "in other function"? Do you mean from another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, code would help answer the question. However, What you can do is something like(if I even understand what you are asking):

```
boolean running = false;
public void StartGame()
if (thread !== null)
   {
    thread= new Thread(this) <-------(if your class implements Runnable)
    running = true
    thread.start();
   }
 public void run()
 {
 while(running){
 //Code you want to execute  
 EndGame()
 }
 public void EndGame()
 {
 if (thread == null)
   {
   return;
   }
 else
  running = false;
  //anything else you want to do (exit, any other methods, etc.)
 }
```

Comment: If I helped you, I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer, thanks. If not, ask me your concerns and I will answer. @ThoaiLeMinh